# Can't See Video received from other users/tabs in Peer js and WebRTC Video Chat App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, peerjs

So I was Building a Video chat Website using Peer Js and I am able to see my own video but when loggin in from another tab I can't see the other user's video stream...
Here is my code. Thanks in advance.
Here's the client side code...

```
const socket = io();
const myPeer = new Peer(userID, {
  host: "/",
  port: 3001,
});

myPeer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", roomID, userID);
});

// Video wala part
const videoGrid = document.querySelector(".videoGrid");
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer(stream);
      const userVideo = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        console.log("User Video: ", userVideoStream);
        addVideoStream(userVideo, userVideoStream);
      });
    });
    socket.on("user-connected", (userID) => {
      console.log("user Connected", userID);
      connectToNewUser(userID, stream);
    });
  });

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    console.log("User Video: ", userVideoStream);
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  });
  call.on("close", () => {
    video.remove();
  });
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    video.play();
  });
  videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

Here's the server side...

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);
  });
});
```

I was following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/DvlyzDZDEq4

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the other user's video stream is not being properly added to the video grid. Make sure that the function call to add the other user's video stream is being executed and that the correct video element is being passed in as the first parameter.

Another possibility is that there is an issue with the WebRTC connection between the two users. Check that both users have a stable internet connection and that their browsers and devices support WebRTC.

If these suggestions do not solve the problem, it may be helpful to try using a library like SimplePeer or WebRTC.io, which handle some of the more complex aspects of WebRTC.